# how to get lat and lon from google map api v2 by user select

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I need to let user select Custom location on Map in Application and get target Lat And Lon

is it possible for android apps?
if yes:
how to do it?
what about min-SDK version? Does it works on API 10 ?

Comment: see https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#getProjection()

Comment: that's good but not in my country, 403. That’s an error. Your client does not have permission to get URL /android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap from this server. (Client IP address: *.*.*.*) We're sorry, but this service is not available in your country. That’s all we know

Comment: what? what are you talking about?

Comment: i live in Iran, can not access to developers.google.com without vpn,trying to get vpn, thank you

Comment: so see any local docs for `com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap`